# How to know the number of key/value pairs in a JSON response?

Tags: jquery

I have this lines at my ajax request:

```
      success: function (response) {
        var result = $.parseJSON(response);
```

Since the response is an array of key/value pairs, how to know the number of pairs?

Comment: You mean array of `Object`? Or an `Object` with multiple properties?

Answer (score 2):

If it's an Array like Object you can use the following:

```
console.log(Object.keys(result).length)
```

If it's just an Array you can use:

```
console.log(result.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use length for that:

```
console.log(result.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way because `.length` only works with `array` not with `object`. so

```
var count = 0;
for(var key in json)
    if(json.hasOwnProperty(key))
        count++;
alert(count);
```

**N.B:** if it is an `array` then go with `.length`
   alert(result.length);